# Passing Command Line Arguments to Rack-App in Nginx with Passenger

Tags: ruby, nginx, passenger, rack

We have a Sinatra / Rack application. We're using Nginx with the Passenger module installed, and the Sinatra / Rack app is being instantiated by Passenger (I hope I'm getting all the verbs correct here).

Configuration for my Rack application comes in the form of command line arguments (e.g. `mqhost=localhost mqport=5672 mquser=foo mqpass=bar`). These are accessed in the Rack app via `ENV['mqhost']`.

All these parameters are also set as environment variables, e.g. `$MQHOST`, `$MQPORT`, etc.

**Q1**: How do I get Passenger to pass these command line arguments to the Rack app when it instantiates it?
**Q2**: If I cannot pass these as command line arguments, is there a way I can force Passenger to call a bash script that sets these environment variables?

I've checked the documentation and another dev and I spent an hour or two trying various things to little success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't.
2. You don't have to use a bash script. Just set it directly with `passenger_set_cgi_param`. There's a whole chapter in the manual regarding environment variables: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#about_environment_variables

   But if you really want to do it from a bash script, try using the wrapper script approach: http://blog.phusion.nl/2008/12/16/passing-environment-variables-to-ruby-from-phusion-passenger/

Comment: Thanks. The unfortunately part of using `passenger_set_cgi_param` is that the environment variables end up in the logs. Which means if I set a password, it'll be in our logs. Do you know if there's a way around this?

Comment: Use the wrapper script approach, as I linked to.